# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_aer'

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am trying to perform some noise simulations using the [Aer Provider](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_provider.html). I read through a tutorials [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_noise.html#custom-noise-models), but I am not able to really implement the `qiskit_aer`. When I tried `import qiskit_aer.noise as noise`, it shows me the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_aer'`. I tried `pip install qiskit_aer` but it returns `Requirement already satisfied`. How can I implement this module? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace `qiskit_aer` was introduced in 0.11. Try `pip install "qiskit-aer>=0.11.0"` or `pip install -U qiskit-aer`.